# Signing-in to use Live SDK, Windows Store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am developing an application (Windows Store) to access SkyDrive content. To login to Live I am using the below code snippet.

```
        try
        {

            var uri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf"; 
            var authorizeUri = new StringBuilder(uri);

            authorizeUri.AppendFormat("?client_id={0}&", "000000004C0DE9B7"); //This is my Client ID
            authorizeUri.AppendFormat("scope={0}&", "wl.signin");             
            authorizeUri.AppendFormat("response_type={0}&", "code");
            authorizeUri.AppendFormat("redirect_uri={0}", (""));  //I don't have redirect URL.

            LiveAuthClient auth = new LiveAuthClient(authorizeUri.ToString());

            LiveLoginResult loginResult = await auth.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.basic" });
            if (loginResult != null)
            {
                if (loginResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
                {
                    this.txtStatus.Text = "Signed in";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (LiveAuthException exception)
        {
            this.txtStatus.Text = exception.Message+ " Error";   
        }
    }
```

With this I am always getting the below exception:
"The app is not configured correctly to use Live Connect services. ..."

I tried to get Package identity for my Windows Store app. Since, it is taking me to paid registration page, I have not done that. [ https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/en-us/account/signup/start ]
I am not sure if that is the cause for the problem.

I have also tried this link to register my app. This too is not working.

https://manage.dev.live.com/build?wa=wsignin1.0

I appreciate if someone could help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Windows Store app to use Live Connect APIs, it needs to have a Package Identity which you can only get my registering as a Windows Store Developer.

Windows Phone, iOS and Android apps need only the Client ID.  All other apps need Client ID, Client Secret and Redirect Domain.

That is why it's not working.  For more information, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826541.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: And what do you do once you have this Package Identity? Where do you put it?